# Error:(175) Attribute "adSize" already defined with incompatible format. (Admob)

Tags: java, android, admob, interstitial

I want to integrate AdMob in my app but it's 3rd day, I can't solve this error:

Here is the stack:

```
C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\xxxxxx\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values\values.xml
Error:(175) Attribute "adSize" already defined with incompatible format.
Error:(142) Original attribute defined here.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\25.0.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

How I can integrate AdMob in my app?

Comment: can you share your layout where you have used admob.

Comment: need some more info ??

Comment: i'm not using any layout because it's interstitial ad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved myself by deleting duplicate "adSize" attributes from my xml.